Net MAUI MAPS Dark Mode
i've read this
How to display google maps in dark mode in a .NET MAUI (Android) app
but gives NO real answer (MapType.StreetNight does NOT exists).. is it possibile to set dark/light mode in a map control in a MAUI app?
no way to find a solution somewhere

You need this for both Android and iOS?

@FreakyAli if possible.. I've also considered the use of OpenStreetMaps (or any map possibile), but I've no idea where to start
I have to use it only in android and iOS (no windows/tyzen etc)

First of all, there is an issue about Customize map style. You can follow up it. And for a workaround, you can call the platform native code to do that.

On the iOS

The Map's native control is MauiMKMapView that implement the MKMapView, so you can set the overrideUserInterfaceStyle property to get the dark mode.
Create the custom handler for the Map:
namespace MauiAppTest.Platforms.iOS
{
    public class CustomMapHandler : MapHandler
    {
        protected override void ConnectHandler(MauiMKMapView platformView)
        {
            platformView.OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
        }
    }
}

In addition, you also use the instance of the Map control to do that in the Page's OnHandlerChanged method, Such as:
(mapname.Handler.PlatformView as MauiMkMapView)
     .OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;


On the Android

The map control uses the google map. So you can read the official document about Add a Styled Map.
First of all, create your dark mode JSON file (buid action is embedded resource) about Style Reference for Maps SDK for Android. You can set the dark mode color by yourself.
And then, you can alo create the custom handler for the Android platform:
namespace MauiAppTest.Platforms.Android
{
    class CustomMapHandler : MapHandler
    {
        protected override void ConnectHandler(MapView platformView)
        {
            var googlemap = this.Map;
            var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiAppTest.dark_map_style.json");
            string json = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream!))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            googlemap.SetMapStyle(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions(json));
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
        }
       
    }
}

Or you can just implement the IOnMapReadyCallback like the google map official document did:
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
           var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
           using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiAppTest.dark_map_style.json");
           string json = string.Empty;
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream!))
           {
               json = reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
           googlemap.SetMapStyle(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions(json));
    }
}

Finally, use the custom handler in the MauiProgram.cs:
UseMauiMaps().ConfigureMauiHandlers((handlers) =>
                {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Map), typeof(MauiAppTest.Platforms.Android.CustomMapHandler));
#elif IOS
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Map), typeof(MauiAppTest.Platforms.iOS.CustomMapHandler));
#endif
                }); 

================================
You can just get the Handler in the HandlerChanged method or in a button clicked event:
In the xaml:
<Map x:Name="map" ..../>

In the Page's OnHandlerChanged method or a button clicked event:
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
{
           base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if IOS
           (map.Handler.PlatformView as MauiMkMapView)
            .OverrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIKit.UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark;
#elif ANDROID
            var googlemap = (map.Handler as MapHandler).Map;
            var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiAppTest.dark_map_style.json");
            string json = string.Empty;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream!))
            {
                json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            googlemap.SetMapStyle(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions(json));
#endif
}


Thank you.  with .net 8.0 and with Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps (and copying your code) gives me anerror
Type androidx.collection.ArraySetKt is defined multiple times: C:\Users\ddepa.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.jvm\1.3.0.2\buildTransitive\net7.0-android33.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-jvm.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class, C:\Users\ddepa.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0....\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar:androidx/collection/ArraySetKt.class
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000:

@DenisDePauli You don't have to install the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps, Just add the Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps NuGet package and then use my code.

Sorry but doesn't work  this line => googlemap.SetMapStyle(new Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions(json));
Error CS0234 Il tipo o il nome dello spazio dei nomi 'Gms' non esiste nello spazio dei nomi 'VTR_Mobile.Platforms.Android'. Probabilmente manca un riferimento all'assembly. VTR Mobile (net8.0-android34.0) C:\Progetti\net\VTR Mobile\VTR Mobile\Platforms\Android\CustomMapHandler.cs
(Missing assembly)
My  Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps is version 8.0.40

Zheang don't ask me why.. if I remove namespace from Android.Gms.Maps.Model.MapStyleOptions and add an using directive... works. Strange but works :D

Thank you!!! I'll try to load my "night version"

Done all... but never passes into handler (even if I change theme)... I'm SURE I've copied all (obviously  I've changed namespaces) but nothing...harder than i believe...

Did you try to make the ManActivity implement the IOnMapReadyCallback interface for the android? Or you can try to get the hnaldler in my update answer. @DenisDePauli
